# Set false in specific column to all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID    Name 
1     test1
2     test2
```

Now I added new column `IsConfirmed`. And this column contain `null` in all rows.

```
ID    Name   IsConfirmed
1     test1     null
2     test2     null
```

How can I set `false` to `IsConfirmed` column to all rows in the table using T-SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET IsConfirmed=0
WHERE isConfirmed is Null
```

Comment: +1 But as a safety measure I would suggest using a WHERE clause: `WHERE IsConfirmed IS NULL` It's a bit redundant in your case but it's never too early to learn to avoid disaster. An UPDATE query without a filter has been the source of many a data mishap.

Comment: That made me nervous too just writing it without a WHERE, but I didn't want to confuse the OP. Good point though.

Answer (score 2):

[@JohnFx's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793342/297408) is a perfect solution to the problem in hand. However, you might want to be interested to know how to prevent this kind of situation from appearing and, at the same time, possibly to solve other potential issues.

In particular, the fact that you wanted to replace the NULLs with 0s immediately might indicate that you never wanted the column to hold NULLs in the first place. If that is actually the case, you should have added the column with the `NOT NULL` specifier:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD IsConfirmed bit NOT NULL
```

Of course, if you try to add a `NOT NULL` column to a non-empty table, you'll get an error if you do not *also* provide a default value for the column, because SQL Server would attempt to add the column with NULLs, which, according to the definition, are not allowed. So, add `NOT NULL` columns like this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD IsConfirmed bit NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT DF_tablename_IsConfirmed DEFAULT (0)
```

The `CONSTRAINT DF_tablename_IsConfirmed` part is optional, you can leave just `DEAFULT (0)`, but I would still recommend you to give explicit names to all your constraints, including the defaults, because that way it would be easier for you to drop/recreate them. And for the same reason (to make your managing the constraints easier), it would be better for you to use fixed patterns in naming the constraints. The pattern in the above statement (`DF` for `DEFAULT`, followed by the table name, followed by the column name) is just an example, you could very well come up a different one. But once you have, just be consistent.